# Can't write Double word on STM32F429 using HAL driver

Tags: stm32, hal

I am trying to write `uint64_t`(double word) variable into the flash memory, without success though. Here is the code.

```c
#define APPLICATION_START_ADDRESS                                   0x8008000

void flashErase(uint8_t startSector, uint8_t numberOfSectors)
{
    HAL_FLASH_Unlock();

    Flash_eraseInitStruct.TypeErase     = FLASH_TYPEERASE_SECTORS;
    Flash_eraseInitStruct.VoltageRange  = FLASH_VOLTAGE_RANGE_3;
    Flash_eraseInitStruct.Sector        = startSector;
    Flash_eraseInitStruct.NbSectors     = numberOfSectors;

    if(HAL_FLASHEx_Erase(&Flash_eraseInitStruct, &Flash_halOperationSectorError) != HAL_OK)
    {
        Flash_raiseError(errHAL_FLASHEx_Erase);
    }

    HAL_FLASH_Lock();
}

int main(void)
{
    HAL_Init();
    main_clockSystemInit();
    __IO uint64_t word =  0x1234567890;

    flashErase(2, 1);
//  flashProgramWord(aTxBuffer, APPLICATION_START_ADDRESS, 2 );
    HAL_FLASH_Unlock();
    HAL_FLASH_Program(FLASH_TYPEPROGRAM_DOUBLEWORD, APPLICATION_START_ADDRESS, word);
}
```

I get error flag raised `PGSERR` and `PGAERR`. The erase operation goes without problems. But programming returns ERROR.
Some Ideas?

Comment: I advice the register approach.  No magic HAL functions. FLASH write function using registers - 10 minutes, "easy" HAL library one - many hours or days.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no STM32F249, did you mean STM32F429?

In order to use 64 bit programming, V<sub>PP</sub> (BOOT0) has to be powered by 8 - 9 Volts. Is it?

See the [Reference Manual](https://www.st.com/resource/en/reference_manual/dm00031020.pdf) Section 3.6.2

[image]

By the way,

```
__IO uint64_t word =  0x1234567890;
```

would not work as (presumably) expected. It is a 32 bit architecture, integer constants will be truncated to 32 bits, unless there is an `L` suffix. `U` wouldn't hurt either, because the variable is unsigned. `__IO` is unnecessary.

```
uint64_t word =  0x1234567890UL;
```